# Weird behavior when pinch zooming an ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, ontouchlistener, pinchzoom

I have an ImageView to which I added an OnTouchListener so that I can zoom in and out the latter using pinch gesture with two fingers. I'm using the code below, but I'm having a problem with resizing the actual Bitmap. The latter gets blurred, stays the same size, and gets overlayed with a resized version of the image, as if it just puts the new image on top of the old one instead of replacing it. I'm thinking there's a problem with the drawMatrix method...

```
    int touchState;
    final int IDLE = 0;
    final int TOUCH = 1;
    final int PINCH = 2;
    float dist0, distCurrent;

    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        boolean handledHere = false;

        float distx, disty;

        final int action = event.getAction();

        switch(action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            //A pressed gesture has started, the motion contains the initial starting location.
            touchState = TOUCH;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            //A non-primary pointer has gone down.
            touchState = PINCH;

            //Get the distance when the second pointer touch
            distx = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
            disty = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
            dist0 = FloatMath.sqrt(distx * distx + disty * disty);

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            //A change has happened during a press gesture (between ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP).
            if(touchState == PINCH){                        
                //Get the current distance
                distx = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
                disty = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
                distCurrent = FloatMath.sqrt(distx * distx + disty * disty);

                drawMatrix((ImageView) view);
            } 

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            //A pressed gesture has finished.
            touchState = IDLE;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            //A non-primary pointer has gone up.
            touchState = TOUCH;
            break;

        }

        return handledHere;
    }

    private void drawMatrix(ImageView view){
        float curScale = distCurrent/dist0;
        if (curScale < 0.1){
            curScale = 0.1f;    
        }

        view.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap originalBitmap = view.getDrawingCache();
        Bitmap resizedBitmap;    
        int newHeight = (int) (view.getHeight() * curScale);
        int newWidth = (int) (view.getWidth() * curScale);
        resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(originalBitmap, newWidth, newHeight, false);
        view.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap); 

    }
```

When I zoom in and out several times, here's how it becomes...
[image]

Thanks for any help I can get.

Answer (score 1):

Actualy you are calling the draw function in onmove so it keeps on calling it when you move your finger.So the images generated with the new height and width are been setting to imageview which is alredy set der. Try removing all the views before setting the resized image to the imageview.Hope this will solve your problem.

```
private void drawMatrix(ImageView view){
        float curScale = distCurrent/dist0;
        if (curScale < 0.1){
            curScale = 0.1f;    
        }

        view.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap originalBitmap = view.getDrawingCache();
        Bitmap resizedBitmap;    
        int newHeight = (int) (view.getHeight() * curScale);
        int newWidth = (int) (view.getWidth() * curScale);
        resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(originalBitmap, newWidth, newHeight, false);
        view.removeallviews();
        view.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap); 

    }
```

Comment: I am sorry it will not work with the imageview .I  was late to check with it.Actually am looking out to solve this will punch back soon wen I get this done..let me see

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking forward to your solution

Answer (score 0):

You may use the TouchImageView class [https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/example/touch/TouchImageView.java].
Which gives nice Zoom in and zoom out functionality for image view.

Comment: I tried it, the thing is I've already made it possible to drag it within a specific area. With TouchImageView, to make it zoomable only within that specific area, I have to set it's height and width to that of the area, but then if I do that I won't be able to drag other ImageView that I drop into the area... I need something that will zoom the ImageView itself, not only the image inside it within the area of the ImageView. D'you understand?